# how to make an update statment more optimal

Tags: oracle

i have to update 10 different fields in 4 different tables on a regular basis

this is the script for 1 field in 1 table:

```
UPDATE MCA_table
SET REAL_RGUS = 'Y'
WHERE PART_NUMBER IN 
      (SELECT DISTINCT MCA.PART_NUMBER
      FROM MCA_table MCA
      INNER JOIN refP_table REFP ON REFP.POID = MCA.PART_NUMBER
      WHERE MCA.REAL_RGUS IS NULL AND REFP.REAL_RGUS = 'Y');
```

i created a stored procedure based on the above script that does all the above updates sequentially but having run for about 50 minutes, it is still going and am not sure if i have written it in the most optimal way; i may be trying to be too clever

help appreciated :)

Comment: the part updating the 1st table finished and it took about 50 minutes :(

Comment: Table definition, including constraints and indexes and a query plan would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be trying to do:

```
UPDATE MCA_table
SET REAL_RGUS = 'Y'
WHERE REAL_RGUS IS NULL
AND PART_NUMBER IN (SELECT POID
    FROM refP_table
    WHERE REAL_RGUS = 'Y')
```

But that would depend on the schema and data. So don't use unless you are sure it is correct for **your** situation.

Comment: thanks. very useful. i amended the code and it is moving much much faster :)